# focus a field in a NSTableCellView for instant editing

Tags: swift, macos, focus, nstableview, nstablecellview

I want to set the focus on one of two editfields in a NSTableCellView in a table with one column in a row programaticly, so that a user can instantly edit the field. 
In my example I can select the row (after pressing a button), but I cann´t find a way to set the focus on a special field.

I my example I want to set the cursor on the tiltle field in row 3.

```
class MainVC: NSViewController, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate
{ var t = [Item]()
  @IBOutlet weak var itemTV: NSTableView!
  @IBAction func actionBu(_ sender: Any)
  { 
    let indexSet = IndexSet(integer: 2)
    itemTV.selectRowIndexes(indexSet, byExtendingSelection: false)
    itemTV.scrollRowToVisible(2)
  }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: How about `NSTableView`s `editColumn(_:row:with:select:)`?

Comment: `UITextfield` has a method `becomeFirstResponder`

Comment: @user1046037 Tags osx and nstableview indicate a macOS question and Apple says about `becomeFirstResponder`: "Never invoke this method directly".

Comment: Did you try `makeFirstResponder` ?

Comment: how  can I get a reference to to textfield to call ``makeFirstResponder``?

Comment: Did you try `editColumn(_:row:with:select:)`?

Comment: yes, tried: ``itemTV.editColumn(0, row: 2, with: nil, select: true)
``but no effect. I wondered which of the 2 edit fields should get the focus, but no one got focus (both editfieldes are in an ``NSTableCellView'' in column 0

Comment: @user1046037 I tried to get the NSTableCellView with ``viewCol0Row2 = itemTV.view(atColumn: 0, row: 2, makeIfNecessary: false)``but I get ``TableFocus.ItemTableCellView``as type. How can I get the NSTableCellView to call ``makeFirstResponder `` on its textfield.

Comment: @user1046037 trying ``(itemTV.view(atColumn: 0, row: 2, makeIfNecessary: false)! as! ItemTableCellView).window!.makeFirstResponder(nil)`` did not work

Comment: Which textfield is connected to `textField` of the cell view?

Comment: Both are connected ``  @IBOutlet weak var name: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var title: NSTextField!``

Comment: So no text field is connected to the `textField` outlet of the cell view? Does `editColumn` work if you also connect this outlet?

Comment: @Willeke: No, both textfield outlets in ``class ItemTableCellView: NSTableCellView`` are connected with the textfields in the cellview in IB.  ``editcolumn`` called in ``@IBAction func actionBu`` on the tableview outlet has no visible effect. If I press a letter after pressing the button the row is selected, but no editing is possible.

Comment: I meant "connect the `textField` outlet of the cell view to the text field", but it doesn't work. `editColumn` selects the first text field. Is the text field editable? Can you edit the field when you click on it?

Comment: yes, the textfield is editable. With the mouse I have to click once to select the row and another time to edit a field.

Comment: if I press tab twice I also can edit the textfield. Could it be a solution to simulate the tab- keystrokes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to all helping commands, I found an solution

```
@IBAction func actionBu(_ sender: Any)
  { self.view.window!.makeFirstResponder(itemTV.view(atColumn: 0, row: 2, makeIfNecessary: true)?.subviews[0])
  }
```

works fine for me,